# express can't find only one static file out of many

Tags: express, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN app but I am having trouble getting express to find a single static file out of others that have not had a problem. I have listed the relevant code below.

```
//server.js 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'js')));

//index.html 
  <script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script> (subdirectory path under /client/public)
  <script src="/angular/angular.js"></script>    (^same)
  <script src="/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script> (^same) 
  <script src="/app.js"></script> (subdirectory path under /client/js)
```

^ all of these work fine

```
<script src="/controllers/homecontroller.js"></script> (subdirectory path under /client/js
```

^ express cannot find this. I do not understand what I am doing wrong; if someone could please inform me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you double-check for typos? Uppercase/lowercase matters, too.

Comment: yes, I've checked multiple times. I've moved it into the js directory directly instead of a subdirectory of js, 'controllers' and express is able to find it. I would rather not have the project constructed this way, if you can think of anything else that may be an issue please let me know.